# Improve Community bot replacement edit summary

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary, link-rot, automatic-edits

In the context of the Community bot URL replacement run addressed in ['Links to HTML versions of RFC's need to move from "tools" to "datatracker"'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367881) it became clear that the replacement edit summary is not really helpful but merely states the obvious

```
replaced http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc
```

which then results in questions like [mine on meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412066/1729265) asking for a reason.

As was confirmed in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412066/community-replaced-http-tools-ietf-org-html-rfc-with-https-www-rfc-editor-or#comment872191_412124) there, that content is created automatically:

> The comment is put in through our dev route for url-rewriting. Auto-generated based on the exact url being substituted.

I would propose to update this by adding a link to an explanatory article, e.g. like this

```
replaced rfc URLs, see meta.stackexchange.com/q/367881
```

Comment: *[RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)*. *[URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)*. *[URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)*.